# Ionic/Cordova Social Sharing

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I added the plugin to my app like so: 
 `cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git`

Here's my code in my controller:

```
$scope.OtherShare = function(){
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('myTitle',null,null,'sometingIShareHEre');
}
```

My code works well on my android device.  But in iOS it only works after I exit the app then goes back to it.  I tried adding `$ionicPlatform.ready` before/after button click but it didn't changed a thing?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is strange, I am guessing this would be a `device.ready` issue. Try wrapping up your code in the device ready callback like

```
$scope.OtherShare = function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        window.plugins.socialsharing.share('myTitle',null,null,'sometingIShareHEre');
    }, false);
}
```

In Ionic

```
$scope.OtherShare = function(){
  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
      window.plugins.socialsharing.share('myTitle',null,null,'sometingIShareHEre');
  });
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm also guessing that it's a device.ready issue. And as I mentioned, I already did something like you posted but no good, and I only encountered this on iOS, I also checked the logs from xcode, but I saw that plugins were loaded as the app started, but I don't know why it doesn't hit if I don't exit the app.. hmmm

Comment: and actually, even when using the cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin, I still don't hit the plugin unless I restart the app

Comment: then I'm sorry bro. I couldn't figure it out what's happening here. You can try opening an issue in this plugin repository.

Comment: yeah it's fine.. can you give me link

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I am having the same problem.